# How to correctly configure which implementation Spring should choose?

Tags: java, spring

I would like to know the "best" way to have, in config (application.yml), the preferred implementation for initialising a specific bean.

Scenario: I have a Service, Service.java, and two implementations, ServiceImpA.java and ServiceImpB.java, It's trivially easy to point to one implementation or the other with the spring provided annotation @Qualifier("?"), as an implementation is @Autowired. I'm wondering about the semantics for when configuring the value of @Qualifier, inside application.yml. This is java11 and

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

Comment: You cannot configure the value of `@Qualifier` inside the properties. Instead use profiles and attach the bean to a profile.

Comment: I feared this. It's overkill to create a new profile for this, in my case.

Comment: Marten, I just checked you out on 'Goodreads'; I'm honoured.

Comment: Instead of a profile you can also use a property and use `@ConditionalOnProperty` to enable/disable one or the other.

Comment: @ConditionalOnProperty was EXACTLY what I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @M. Deinum pointed out in the comments; @ConditionalOnProperty was the way forward.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty